# Windows 7: Can files located in C:\Windows\Installer be deleted?

Tags: windows-7, installer

The folder (*C:\Windows\Installer*) on my Windows 7 installation holds 1GB of installers are these necessary or can these be deleted ? If so are there any other places where Windows 7 saves the installers which are used to install files and can they be removed ?

Comment: Is 1GB really worth it these days? I mean, one can buy a 2TB drive for very reasonable prices, and 1tb drives are almost given away in cereal boxes.

Comment: well it does matter if my C drive is collecting clutter unnecessarily I just needed to know if those were necessary files or not

Comment: 1 GB really is a lot when it's actually 9 GB (as it is on my machine), and your boot volume is an SSD with only 112 GB capacity...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't delete this folder or its content.

Use the **[Windows Installer CleanUp Utility](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Security/Secure-cleaning/Windows-Installer-CleanUp-Utility.shtml)** instead as it will properly unregister files.

Comment: Stay clear of that tool if you really don't need it, see http://superuser.com/questions/173981/unable-to-uninstall-visual-studio-2008-could-not-open-components-key why...

Comment: This utility doesn't work for Windows 7.  I am unable to find the latest version that works for Windows 7.  I've tried 2 downloaded versions already.

Comment: @Mr.MacGyver: Did you run it as administrator? Because it works for me, even on Windows 8...

Comment: probably not.. I'll try that.

Comment: I also found this won't work for Windows 7, and I can't find any way to address this for Windows 7.  I have that folder taking up 9 GB of my 112 GB SSD boot volume - vexing.

Answer (score 5):

You can safely [compress](http://www.ehow.com/how_2073271_compress-folder-windows.html) C:\Windows\Installer if you want to.

Comment: if you do, will the uninstall or repair options still work in Programs and Features in Windows 7?

Comment: @Mr.MacGyver: Yes, they will.