# SQL Server Express 2008 R2 Installation error at Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, sql-server, sql, sql-server-2008

I created an install script that will install SQL Server 2008 R2 on Windows XP SP3, Windows Vista and Windows 7.

One of the command that I used in the installation is for silent installation of SQL Server 2008 R2. When I install it on Windows XP everything works just fine but when I try to install it on Windows 7 I get an error.

**What am I doing wrong?**

Here is the command line that i use:

```
Setup.exe /ConfigurationFile=Mysetup.ini
```

Mysetup.ini file:

```
;SQL SERVER 2008 R2 Configuration File
;Version 1.0, 5 May 2010
;

[SQLSERVER2008]
; Specify the Instance ID for the SQL Server features you have specified. SQL Server directory structure, registry structure, and service names will reflect the instance ID of the SQL Server instance.
INSTANCEID="MSSQLSERVER"

; Specifies a Setup work flow, like INSTALL, UNINSTALL, or UPGRADE. This is a required parameter.
ACTION="Install"

; Specifies features to install, uninstall, or upgrade. The list of top-level features include SQL, AS, RS, IS, and Tools. The SQL feature will install the database engine, replication, and full-text. The Tools feature will install Management Tools, Books online, Business Intelligence Development Studio, and other shared components.
FEATURES=SQLENGINE

; Displays the command line parameters usage
HELP="False"

; Specifies that the detailed Setup log should be piped to the console.
INDICATEPROGRESS="False"

; Setup will not display any user interface.
QUIET="False"

; Setup will display progress only without any user interaction.
QUIETSIMPLE="True"

; Specifies that Setup should install into WOW64. This command line argument is not supported on an IA64 or a 32-bit system.
;X86="False"

; Specifies the path to the installation media folder where setup.exe is located.
;MEDIASOURCE="z:\"

; Detailed help for command line argument ENU has not been defined yet.
ENU="True"

; Parameter that controls the user interface behavior. Valid values are Normal for the full UI, and AutoAdvance for a simplied UI.
; UIMODE="Normal"

; Specify if errors can be reported to Microsoft to improve future SQL Server releases. Specify 1 or True to enable and 0 or False to disable this feature.
ERRORREPORTING="False"

; Specify the root installation directory for native shared components.
;INSTALLSHAREDDIR="D:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server"

; Specify the root installation directory for the WOW64 shared components.
;INSTALLSHAREDWOWDIR="D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server"

; Specify the installation directory.
;INSTANCEDIR="D:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server"

; Specify that SQL Server feature usage data can be collected and sent to Microsoft. Specify 1 or True to enable and 0 or False to disable this feature.
SQMREPORTING="False"

; Specify a default or named instance. MSSQLSERVER is the default instance for non-Express editions and SQLExpress for Express editions. This parameter is required when installing the SQL Server Database Engine (SQL), Analysis Services (AS), or Reporting Services (RS).
INSTANCENAME="SQLEXPRESS"
SECURITYMODE=SQL
SAPWD=SystemAdmin

; Agent account name
AGTSVCACCOUNT="NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE"

; Auto-start service after installation.
AGTSVCSTARTUPTYPE="Manual"

; Startup type for Integration Services.
;ISSVCSTARTUPTYPE="Automatic"

; Account for Integration Services: Domain\User or system account.
;ISSVCACCOUNT="NT AUTHORITY\NetworkService"

; Controls the service startup type setting after the service has been created.
;ASSVCSTARTUPTYPE="Automatic"

; The collation to be used by Analysis Services.
;ASCOLLATION="Latin1_General_CI_AS"

; The location for the Analysis Services data files.
;ASDATADIR="Data"

; The location for the Analysis Services log files.
;ASLOGDIR="Log"

; The location for the Analysis Services backup files.
;ASBACKUPDIR="Backup"

; The location for the Analysis Services temporary files.
;ASTEMPDIR="Temp"

; The location for the Analysis Services configuration files.
;ASCONFIGDIR="Config"

; Specifies whether or not the MSOLAP provider is allowed to run in process.
;ASPROVIDERMSOLAP="1"

; A port number used to connect to the SharePoint Central Administration web application.
;FARMADMINPORT="0"

; Startup type for the SQL Server service.
SQLSVCSTARTUPTYPE="Automatic"

; Level to enable FILESTREAM feature at (0, 1, 2 or 3).
FILESTREAMLEVEL="0"

; Set to "1" to enable RANU for SQL Server Express.
ENABLERANU="1"

; Specifies a Windows collation or an SQL collation to use for the Database Engine.
SQLCOLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"

; Account for SQL Server service: Domain\User or system account.
SQLSVCACCOUNT="NT Authority\System"

; Default directory for the Database Engine user databases.
;SQLUSERDBDIR="K:\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL\Data"

; Default directory for the Database Engine user database logs.
;SQLUSERDBLOGDIR="L:\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL\Data\Logs"

; Directory for Database Engine TempDB files.
;SQLTEMPDBDIR="T:\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL\Data"

; Directory for the Database Engine TempDB log files.
;SQLTEMPDBLOGDIR="T:\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL\Data\Logs"

; Provision current user as a Database Engine system administrator for SQL Server 2008 R2 Express.
ADDCURRENTUSERASSQLADMIN="True"

; Specify 0 to disable or 1 to enable the TCP/IP protocol.
TCPENABLED="1"

; Specify 0 to disable or 1 to enable the Named Pipes protocol.
NPENABLED="0"

; Startup type for Browser Service.
BROWSERSVCSTARTUPTYPE="Automatic"

; Specifies how the startup mode of the report server NT service. When
; Manual - Service startup is manual mode (default)
; Automatic - Service startup is automatic mode.
; Disabled - Service is disabled
;RSSVCSTARTUPTYPE="Automatic"

; Specifies which mode report server is installed in.
; Default value: “FilesOnly”
;RSINSTALLMODE="FilesOnlyMode"

; Accept SQL Server 2008 R2 license terms
IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS="TRUE"
;setup.exe /CONFIGURATIONFILE=Mysetup.ini /INDICATEPROGRESS

--------------------------- End of ini file -------------------------------------
```

And i get this error:

```
2010-08-31 18:05:53 Slp: Error result: -2068119551
2010-08-31 18:05:53 Slp: Result facility code: 1211
2010-08-31 18:05:53 Slp: Result error code: 1
2010-08-31 18:05:53 Slp: Sco: Attempting to create base registry key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, machine
2010-08-31 18:05:53 Slp: Sco: Attempting to open registry subkey
2010-08-31 18:05:53 Slp: Sco: Attempting to open registry subkey Software\Microsoft\PCHealth\ErrorReporting\DW\Installed
2010-08-31 18:05:53 Slp: Sco: Attempting to get registry value DW0200
2010-08-31 18:05:53 Slp: Submitted 1 of 1 failures to the Watson data repository
```

What the meaning of this?

What do i need to do to fix that problem?

Here is the Summary file:

```
Overall summary:
Final result: SQL Server installation failed. To continue, investigate the reason for the failure, correct the problem, uninstall SQL Server, and then rerun SQL Server Setup.
Exit code (Decimal): -2068119551
Exit facility code: 1211
Exit error code: 1
Exit message: SQL Server installation failed. To continue, investigate the reason for the failure, correct the problem, uninstall SQL Server, and then rerun SQL Server Setup.
Start time: 2010-08-31 18:03:44
End time: 2010-08-31 18:05:51
Requested action: Install
Log with failure: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20100831_180236\Detail.txt

Exception help link: http%3a%2f%2fgo.microsoft.com%2ffwlink%3fLinkId%3d20476%26ProdName%3dMicrosoft%2bSQL%2bServer%26EvtSrc%3dsetup.rll%26EvtID%3d50000%26ProdVer%3d10.50.1600.1%26EvtType%3d0x6121810A%400xC24842DB

Machine Properties:
Machine name: NVR
Machine processor count: 2
OS version: Windows 7
OS service pack:
OS region: United States
OS language: English (United States)
OS architecture: x86
Process architecture: 32 Bit
OS clustered: No

Product features discovered:
Product Instance Instance ID Feature Language Edition Version Clustered

Package properties:
Description: SQL Server Database Services 2008 R2
ProductName: SQL Server 2008 R2
Type: RTM
Version: 10
SPLevel: 0
Installation location: C:\Disk1\setupsql\x86\setup\
Installation edition: EXPRESS

User Input Settings:
ACTION: Install
ADDCURRENTUSERASSQLADMIN: True
AGTSVCACCOUNT: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE
AGTSVCPASSWORD: *
AGTSVCSTARTUPTYPE: Disabled
ASBACKUPDIR: Backup
ASCOLLATION: Latin1_General_CI_AS
ASCONFIGDIR: Config
ASDATADIR: Data
ASDOMAINGROUP:
ASLOGDIR: Log
ASPROVIDERMSOLAP: 1
ASSVCACCOUNT:
ASSVCPASSWORD: *
ASSVCSTARTUPTYPE: Automatic
ASSYSADMINACCOUNTS:
ASTEMPDIR: Temp
BROWSERSVCSTARTUPTYPE: Automatic
CONFIGURATIONFILE: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20100831_180236\ConfigurationFile.ini
CUSOURCE:
ENABLERANU: True
ENU: True
ERRORREPORTING: False
FARMACCOUNT:
FARMADMINPORT: 0
FARMPASSWORD: *
FEATURES: SQLENGINE
FILESTREAMLEVEL: 0
FILESTREAMSHARENAME:
FTSVCACCOUNT:
FTSVCPASSWORD: *
HELP: False
IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS: True
INDICATEPROGRESS: False
INSTALLSHAREDDIR: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\
INSTALLSHAREDWOWDIR: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\
INSTALLSQLDATADIR:
INSTANCEDIR: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\
INSTANCEID: MSSQLSERVER
INSTANCENAME: SQLEXPRESS
ISSVCACCOUNT: NT AUTHORITY\NetworkService
ISSVCPASSWORD: *
ISSVCSTARTUPTYPE: Automatic
NPENABLED: 0
PASSPHRASE: *
PCUSOURCE:
PID: *
QUIET: False
QUIETSIMPLE: True
ROLE: AllFeatures_WithDefaults
RSINSTALLMODE: FilesOnlyMode
RSSVCACCOUNT: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE
RSSVCPASSWORD: *
RSSVCSTARTUPTYPE: Automatic
SAPWD: *
SECURITYMODE: SQL
SQLBACKUPDIR:
SQLCOLLATION: SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
SQLSVCACCOUNT: NT Authority\System
SQLSVCPASSWORD: *
SQLSVCSTARTUPTYPE: Automatic
SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS:
SQLTEMPDBDIR:
SQLTEMPDBLOGDIR:
SQLUSERDBDIR:
SQLUSERDBLOGDIR:
SQMREPORTING: False
TCPENABLED: 1
UIMODE: AutoAdvance
X86: False
Configuration file: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20100831_180236\ConfigurationFile.ini

Detailed results:
Feature: Database Engine Services
Status: Failed: see logs for details
MSI status: Passed
Configuration status: Failed: see details below
Configuration error code: 0x0A2FBD17@1211@1
Configuration error description: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
Configuration log: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20100831_180236\Detail.txt

Rules with failures:
Global rules:
Scenario specific rules:
Rules report file: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20100831_180236\SystemConfigurationCheck_Report.htm
```

What should I do and why does this problem occur?

Answer (score 1):

You sound pretty PC savvy, so I won't give step-by-step instructions, but let me know if you need them.

Basically, it's an issue with the registry permissions.  You need to make sure your account has FULL ACCESS to

`HKLM\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Installer`

It is failing on trying to update the registry.

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for you answer.. 
I logged in as 'Admin' in two different machines with windows 7 and I could not find "HKLM\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Installer".
I found it only in windows XP.
In windows 7 I saw only "HKLM\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows" without 'Installer'.
What should I do ?

Comment: You can see the full log files in here:  
http://www.box.net/shared/uxay022ica

Thanks...

Comment: Comment from @Gliukaz: JNK can you give me step by step instruction as I'm stuck with this issue. And I haven't got `HKLM\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Installer` in my register.

Comment: **Related:** [Been there, done that.](http://superuser.com/questions/173981/unable-to-uninstall-visual-studio-2008-could-not-open-components-key/174198#174198).