# "Windows cannot access the specified device, path, or file, you may not have appropriate permission to access the item" Why? Has windows gone bonkers?

Tags: windows-7, windows, permissions

Whenever i try to access any folder on my computer(Windows 7), it tells me `"Windows cannot access the specified device, path, or file, you may not have appropriate permission to access the item"`, this happens even for `My Computer and Control Panel`. It's driving me nuts! I'll be honest here, I was trying to uninstall `Visual Studio 2013 Community`from my computer by going to `Programs and Features` but for some reason, it was getting stuck at `"Configuring Your System"`. After trying it numerous times, I went to the visual studio installation directory, and removed the installation files from there. I even removed the files from the `C:\Program Data` folder, then i went back to `Programs and Features` and tried to remove the listing there, but I got a dialog box saying `"you don't have sufficient access to uninstall visual studio"`. I googled this problem and found [this solution](https://superuser.com/a/174198) then i tried using the solution, I used `SubinAcl` and changed the registry permissions as mentioned in the solution and ended up like this.!

All the access permissions are set correctly (that's what I can make out...)

(I don't have any reputation on this site that is why i cannot post any images)

Any help will be appriciated A LOT.

**Edit:** Will reinstalling and then **PROPERLY** uninstalling visual studio help?

Comment: So your modifications to the register have done significant harm to your installation.  It unlikely you will be able to reverse those changes.

Comment: Is there any way I can reverse these changes?

Comment: No, you shouldn't have forced those permissions on those registry keys, without knowing without a shadow of a doubt it would solve the problem.  I suspect the reason it didn't work is because you had other issues and now your in a incomplete state.

Comment: I know that it was a stupid idea, but I thought it would solve the problem

Comment: Visual Studio is a very invasive install, and makes many changes to your OS. it is likely that rebuilding windows, will be the path of least resistance.

Comment: @FrankThomas how am I supposed to revert those changes? Any way one thing is for sure, I will never use visual studio again.

Comment: As I said, reinstall windows, or at least restore to a previous state. you are of course free to do whatever you like, but I would say, as someone who uses it daily, and has wide experience with IDEs, Visual studio is one of the best out there. The alternative to the intense install is the anarchy that comes with trying to maintain settings and plugins across multiple instances of eclipse.

Comment: Can I not repair the registry?

Comment: the register will only be part of the problem, and no, probably not, though you may be able to fix the specific issue you have reported. I liken your request to that of someone who ran `sudo chmnod -R 700 /` on a linux box and now wants to reset all their permissions to 'default'. Its possible I suppose, but quite a piece of work to accomplish.

Comment: Could you tell me my best options?

Comment: Have you tried System Restore, http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/restore-system-files-and-settings, or are you locked out of that, even in Safe mode? Alternatively, restoring from your last full image backup using bootable media, presuming you have it, would be easier than reinstalling Windows.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik I tried system restore, but the last restore point (I don't know how) is after the problem started. And i don't have a full image backup....