# Why Does Explorer.Exe hold open file handles to files in C:\Windows\Installer?

Tags: windows-7, file-management, installer

I wanted to use Junction Master to move the files in C:\Windows\Installer off of my SSD and onto a normal HD to save space.

When JM complained that there were files in use (on a freshly rebooted / quiet system), I used Unlocker to view what process has open file handles on files in that dir.

It is Explorer.EXE.    Why Does Explorer.Exe hold open file handles to files in C:\Windows\Installer ?

Comment: See [Windows 7: Can files located in C:\Windows\Installer be deleted?](http://superuser.com/questions/89823/windows-7-can-files-located-in-c-windows-installer-be-deleted) It's an important folder so probably to prevent users from tinkering with it.

Comment: I understand the need for the files in Installer... I don't want to delete them, just move them off my SSD to a hard drive.